# How many shake hands and hugs were exchanged at that party?

Tags: logical-deduction

There are **20** people at this birthday party, where 10 are men, 5 kids and rest women. So, the etiquette here is like follows:

> a. when men meet men for the first time, they greet by shaking hands
>
> b. when men meet women for the first time, they greet with a hug.
>
> c. when women meet women for the first time, they too shake hands with
>   each other.
>
> d. Every Adult greet the birthday boy (man) with both shake hands and
>   hugs.
>
> d. kids just say "hi". No shake hands, no hugs.

So, My question is, How many shake hands and hugs were exchanged at that party?

Comment: Is mention of  **...first time** a must ?

Comment: I think that specifies a "once per pair" relationship, as there's no mention of subsequent meetings.

Comment: some men could be kids, that means there are 10 men, 10 women and 5 kids? :)

Answer (score 1):

> $60$ handshakes and $59$ hugs are performed, assuming everyone meets each other for the first time.

The birthday boy shakes and hugs with each other man and woman:

> $14$ shakes, $14$ hugs

The remaining $9$ men shake hands with each of the other (non-birthday) men:

> $\left(\array{9 \\ 2}\right) = \frac{9*8}{2} = 36$ shakes

The $5$ women shake hands with each of the other women:

> $\left(\array{5 \\ 2}\right) = \frac{5*4}{2} = 10$ shakes

The $9$ men each hug the $5$ women:

> $9*5=45$ hugs

The kids neither handshake nor hug anyone, so they can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If we follow the assumption that 'men' and 'women' are by definition adults, and the remaining are adults (so 10 adult men M, 5 adult women W and 5 kids K, no tricks involved), we have 6 combinations:

MM / MW / MK / WW / WK / KK.

For MM:
10 Men have 45 encounters amongst eachother. (n x (n-1))/2
This leads to 45 handshakes

For MW:
10 men and 5 women imply 50 encouters.
This leads to 50 hugs

For MK:
10 men shake hands and hug the birthday boy (so only one kid interacts, the others just say hi). 
This leads to 10 handshakes and 10 hugs.

For WW:
5 women shaking hands with eachother leads to 10 handshakes (5 x 4)/2, similar as with the men.

For WK:
5 women shake hands and hug the birthday boy (so only one kid interacts, the others just say hi). 
This leads to 5 handshakes and 5 hugs.

For KK:
No handshakes or hugs.

If we make the sum, we get 70 handshakes and 65 hugs.

Comment: The birthday boy is stated to be a man, not a kid.

Comment: You're right. It's just poor wording though, and basically this seems like a math homework (and voted as such). The logic is the similar. Given the VTC passed, I'll not update the answer. (and well, basically you typed it up like that anyway)